# Code to record a screencast in MacOS

Tags: macos

**I need to write a tool that records screen activity on a MacOS desktop and creates a video of it.**

I'm aware that there are multiple tools available that do this already - yet *I need an implementation of my own* for various reasons.

As the issue is a very broad one I will break it down into the following:

**a)** What technologies/skills would I need - programming language (Object C?), graphics API ... ?

**b)** How could I encode the video properly (e.g. Ogg Theora/H.264)?

If anyone knows about open source tools and/or tutorials covering this topic (*only for MacOS!*) please let me know!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the following sample code from Apple: http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/samplecode/OpenGLScreenCapture/
It demonstrate the basics of screen grabbing and movie generation.